# I want to permanently delete app from one Firebase account and add to another account

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I have tried deleting app from one account, it shows message like this

*App now shut down and scheduled to be deleted after 2/5/17, 9:04 AM*

So I added same app to another firebase account but in my android-studio it shows log message like this
V/FirebaseCrash: Firebase Crash Reporting is disabled.

How to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In google developer console,

1. Go to API Manager
2. Enable the "Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API"

for more details   [Refer Report Crashes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#create_your_first_error)

Comment: I enables using Firebase assistant in android-studio.                                                                                                  FirebaseCrash.log("Activity created");
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.ERROR, TAG, "NPE caught");
        FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Firebase non-fatal error on Android"));  Added this code. still it says firebase disabled

Comment: In event log i got this message: _Firebase project created and connected locally to module: app._